# Why does the following code require the (int)?

Tags: java, object

The Java method `Math.round` can be used to round numbers. Which of the following code fragments converts a floating-point number to the nearest integer?

The right answer is:

```
double f = 4.65          
int n = (int) Math.round(f);
```

Why is it not  the following:

```
double f = 4.65;      
int n = Math.round(f);
```

Comment: if you just do Math.round on the double its still a double :) even if its rounded. to set it as int var... you have to use the (int) cast

Comment: @KURN: *"if you just do Math.round on the double its still a double"* Not with Java's `Math.round` methods, it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

[`Math.round(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) returns a `long`, hence the narrowing cast.

Comment: Indeed. The other way to write it would be `int n = Math.round((float)f);` since [`Math.round(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) returns `int`.

Comment: Yeah, don't ever write `int n = Math.round((float)f);` - it's not as accurate.  `(int)Math.round(123456789.4)` is `123456789` but  `Math.round((float)123456789.4)` is `123456792` and the reason is too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Math has two round methods.

```
static long round(double a) 
//Returns the closest long to the argument.

static int round(float a) 
//Returns the closest int to the argument.
```

You are using the first one, which returns a long value, which can store larger integers than int, and cannot be implicitly cast to int.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a `double` to `Math.Round` then you get a `long` as result.
only if you pass a `float` you get a `int` as result.

From the Java Docs:

> round(**double** a)
>              Returns the closest **long** to the argument.
>
> round(**float** a)
>              Returns the closest **int** to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Docs `Math.round(double)` will return a `long` and because a `long` is not an `int` you have to cast it with `(int)`.